# Grub installation failed

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, uefi

I had a good running installation of Debian Jessie, but then I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`.

And then after rebooting, it came directly to the BIOS. I realized that Grub was missing, so I ran a live cd and entered `Rescue mode`, mounted my root partition, + the boot partition and ran these commands:

Grub finds the linux image:

```
root@debian:~# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
Found Ubuntu 16.10 (16.10) on /dev/sdb2
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

And then `grub-install` :

```
root@debian:~# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not prepare Boot variable: No such file or directory
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
```

`lsblk` :

```
root@debian:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  92.6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0 130.4G  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0   573M  0 part /boot/efi
```

Did I do something wrong? Is there too little space on my `/boot/efi` partition?

```
root@debian:~# ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/debian/
total 120
-rwx------ 1 root root 121856 Jul 20 20:29 grubx64.efi
```

`efibootmgr` doesn't show a Debian installation:

```
root@debian:~# efibootmgr --verbose | grep debian
```

Edit :

I keep getting this error every time I try and create a boot loader using `efibootmgr` :

```
grub-install: info: executing efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 3 -w -L grub -l \EFI\grub\grubx64.efi.
Could not prepare Boot variable: No such file or directory
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
```

Comment: Exactly same problem here with ASUS laptop.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Fixed the efibootmgr errors by mounting the Boot variables for `efibootmgr` :

```
# mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
```

And then `efibootmgr` gave me errors about space :

```
Could not prepare Boot variable: No space left on device
```

Fixed that by deleting dump files :

```
# rm /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/dump-*
```

And then ran the usual

```
update-grub 
grub-install -v --target=x86_64-efi --recheck /dev/sda
```

and it ran successfully!

Comment: This worked for me, except that I also had to reboot between the step `rm /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/dump-*` and running `grub-install`.

Comment: i was having exact problem installing galliumos onto chromebook pixel 2013.Had to clear NVRAM using mrchromebook.tech's firmware_utility.sh and then problem went away.

Comment: The dump-* files were tiny, only like 25Kb total,yet this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify the disk containing the loader if your disk is not /dev/sda:

```
efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/nvme0n1 --part 1 --label Ubuntu
```

Comment: this option worked for my, excute before `sudo apt install efibootmgr` , and create to end the boot option , i got to delete other boot options .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu with my Asus motherboard. I did not find any dump files to delete. Or anything big that felt safe to delete.

I was able to fix the issue by rebooting the system with `efi_no_storage_paranoia` kernel command line option. I had already lost the Ubuntu UEFI boot entry. Luckily I could still boot to my Ubuntu partition by going to boot selection in BIOS settings. After that I used the "e" key in grub menu to add that option to the kernel command line. Then I was able to finish my previously failed system upgrade by running `apt -f install`.

If the system is in un-bootable state, one option is to boot from Ubuntu USB stick and fix the issue from there.

If the problem reappears later on I will consider adding that kernel option permanently in `/etc/default/grub`.

The kernel is very paranoid about filling up the UEFI variable space. It reports that it is full even if there is space left. This is intentional to prevent permanently filling up the space on some motherboards. I suspect that with my motherboard this might be too paranoid. Maybe the BIOS does not start garbage collection unless the space gets more full.

Previously I was able to recover from the same situation by using the "Clear CMOS" header on my motherboard. Good to find a software solution.