# grub not working after EndeavourOS installation (via live USB)

Tags: grub2, uefi, endeavouros

I installed EndeavourOS (based on arch linux) via live USB following the guide on my /dev/sda partition where I used to have Ubuntu, which worked fine.
I also have a separate HDD, my /dev/sdb partition, with Windows 10 installed.
Everytime I turn on my PC I get to the grub shell and I can't boot normally into neither of the OS.

This is the output from grub shell:

```
grub>ls
grub>(hd0) (hd1) ... (hd1,gpt2) (hd2,gpt2) (hd1,msdos1)...
```

The partition I need is (hd1,gpt2) so I do:

```
grub>set root (hd1,gpt2)
grub>linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda2
grub>initrd /boot/initramfs_linux.image
grub> boot
```

and it boots normally into EndeavourOS. Then I try to fix my grub installation:

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

And I then get this error:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

I have tried specified the EFI partition following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405472/cannot-find-efi-directory-issue-with-grub-install) answer:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt/EFI
```

but I get:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda1.
grub-install: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda1.
grub-install: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda1.
grub-install: error: disk `hostdisk//dev/sda1' not found.
```

I checked the /mnt/EFI directory:

```
$ls /mnt/EFI/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 21 apr  2019 BOOT
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 24 mar 15.22 ubuntu
```

So I thought maybe the usb live installation didn't format correctly the partions... Is there a way to fix this rather then format everything and start from scratch? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I tried as suggested to refer to /mnt as the efi directory:

```
$ sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt
```

and got this error:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not prepare Boot variable: No space left on device
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
```

Now my /mnt/EFI folder looks like this:

```
$ ls /mnt/EFI
BOOT  endeavouros  ubuntu
$ ls /mnt/EFI/endeavouros
grubx64.efi
$ ls /mnt/EFI/ubuntu
BOOTX64.CSV  fw  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi
```

should I maybe delete the ubuntu folder?

also I have a ton of results running efibootmgr:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,000C,001A,0012,0007,0009,0011,0013,0014,0015,0017,0018,0019,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive
Boot0002* UEFI:Removable Device
Boot0003* UEFI:Network Device
Boot0007  UEFI OS
Boot0009  CD/DVD Drive 
Boot000C* UEFI OS
Boot0011  UEFI OS
Boot0012* Unknown Device
Boot0013  ubuntu
Boot0014  ubuntu
Boot0015  UEFI OS
Boot0017  ubuntu
Boot0018  UEFI OS
Boot0019  ubuntu
Boot001A* UEFI OS
```

SOLVED:
I followed the [guide](https://endeavouros.com/docs/system-rescue/repair-grub-efi-uefi-system/) on the wiki, launching the live system in UEFI (otherwise it won't work).

Answer (score 1):

The efi directory is wrong and should be set to the path where the partition is mounted. Also use `sudo` for `grub-install`:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt
```

**Edit:**

It looks like your efivars (the EEPROM location, not the partition `/dev/sda1`) is full and you need to clean up.

Run `efibootmgr -v` and remove obsolete entries, i.e. if there is an old Ubuntu entry like

```
Boot0014* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,...)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

then you may remove it with

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 0014 -B
```

Also delete `dump-*` files in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`, see this answer: [Grub installation failed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379824/332764).

Yes, you may also remove the `/mnt/EFI/ubuntu` directory, but I don't think it's the cause of the error since `endeavouros/grubx64.efi` was successfully written.

Then try

```
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt
```

again.

Comment: I have tried that before, unsure of what the answer I linked meant with [efi dir]. 
I used to have the same error as I mentioned before, but now I get ```Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not prepare Boot variable: No space left on device
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
```

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: which one should I delete? It's weird is says current boot is ubuntu. I updated the question with the output of `efibootmgr`

Comment: I can't seem to be able to delete the entries ...
```sudo efibootmgr -b 17 -B
Could not delete variable: No space left on device```

Comment: The duplicated `ubuntu` and `UEFI OS` entries look terribly wrong and I have no idea what `UEFI OS` or `Unknown Device` means. 
It _could_ be that your nvram is corrupted and has gone readonly, but I'm not sure. Are there any `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/dump-*` files you can remove?

Comment: I didn't have any dump-* files. I solved by launching live usb (IMPORTANT: selected UEFI mode) then I followed [this guide on the wiki](https://endeavouros.com/docs/system-rescue/repair-grub-efi-uefi-system/) .